# Identificador Único de um Smartphone

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema e necessito capturar um identificador único do Smartphone.

Neste caso, a pessoa acessaria o site pelo Smartphone e o site irá capturar algum identificador único do dispositivo ou até do navegador.
Pensei em algo como IMEI ou o número do telefone, mas não consegui encontrar uma forma de fazer.

Comment: Acho que é bem complicado de se conseguir esse tipo de informação... Talvez o que você possa fazer é tentar gravar algum tipo de informação, seja em forma de cookie ou LocalStorage para tentar identificar o visitante, mesmo assim ainda pode haver falhas.

Answer (score 5):

**Navegador**

Você pode utilizar o `device.uuid`, [clique aqui](http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html5/device.uuid.md.html#device.uuid) para abrir o link sobre *Universally Unique Identifier (UUID)*

```
var string = device.uuid;
```

**Bibliotecas JavaScript úteis**

- [fingerprintJS](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintJS): <sup><sub>*"Fingerprinting is a technique, outlined in the research by Electronic Frontier Foundation, of anonymously identifying a web browser with accuracy of up to 94%."*</sub></sup>
- [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/): *<sup><sub>"Is your browser configuration rare or unique? If so, web sites may be able to track you, even if you limit or disable cookies. Panopticlick tests your browser to see how unique it is based on the information it will share with sites it visits."</sub></sup>*

**Aplicação Android**

Adicione a seguinte permissão no seu AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Para recuperar o IMEI do dispositivo:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imei = tm.getDeviceId();
```

Referências:

[Unique device identification - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738161/unique-device-identification)

Comment: Acho que a ideia dele é que isso pudesse ser feito via browser/javascript e não em um aplicativo nativo ou híbrido =/

Comment: Editei linkando com bibliotecas JavaScript que podem ser úteis

Comment: Vale lembrar que qualquer identificador vindo de um dispositivo ou browser remoto pode ser facilmente forjado. Então não seria adequado se o fim for relacionado à autenticação ou algum tipo de segurança.

Comment: Bem lembrado @utluiz, não me lembrei sobre esse fato que tem a possibilidade de ocorrer.

Comment: O que se faz geralmente é usar um formulário de login tradicional e então colocar um token temporário no browser num cookie. Aí você pode "lembrar" do usuário enquanto o cookie durar. O identificador do celular pode servir como um dado adicional nesse processo, pois seria uma segunda barreira de controle.

Comment: De fato, como o Wakim disse, deve ser capturado pelo navegado.